# density of the set of sequences that eventually converges to 0

Tags: metric-spaces, lp-spaces

My teacher gave me a question and I don't know if my answer is correct (he didn't tell me :( )).

The question was : if I consider the set of all functions that eventually converges to 0, this set is dense in $l^1$ ; what happens with $l^p$ with $p>1$ and $l^{\infty}$ ?

My answer was yes, this set is dense in all spaces size if I take the sequence $(0,0...) (0,1,0...) (..., \text{any sequence} ,0...)$ this converge to  that sequence.

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: If my answer was correct.

Comment: The set of all sequences that converge to 0 isn't a subset of $\ell^1$.

Comment: but if a take the sequence $(1,2,...,100,0,0,0)$ and i sum all absolute values this sum is finite and this secuence is on $l^1$ or i'm wrong?

Comment: Your set is contained in $\ell^{\infty}$ but it is not dense in $\ell^{\infty}$.

Comment: For $1<p<\infty$ every sequence in $\ell^{p}$ converges to $0$, so the set you are considering  is a **superset ** of $\ell^{p}$, not a subset.

Comment: Did you really want to say "eventually *converges to* zero"? Or, did you mean "eventually *becomes constant* zero"? This seems to confuse a lot of people here, can you please clarify?

Comment: And, presuming the latter interpretation, and presuming your solution starts from a sequence $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\in \ell^p$ and constructs a sequence $(a_1,0,0,\ldots),(a_1,a_2,0,\ldots),\ldots,(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,0,0\ldots))$, this is a correct proof. Your proof does not work for $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: Yeah sry my bad, is become constant zero, so this set not is dense on $l^\infty$